# Rust Lifetime of Option::take()

Tags: rust

Here is the code with some problem of lifetime:

```
struct Node<T>(T);

struct Wrapper<'a, T: 'a>(&'a mut Node<T>);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Wrapper<'a, T> {      
    // error: lifetime may not live long enough
    fn func(&mut self) -> &'a mut T {
        &mut self.0 .0
    }
}
```

I fix the problem of the code above:

```
struct Wrapper<'a, T: 'a>(Option<&'a mut Node<T>>);

impl<'a, T: 'a> Wrapper<'a, T> {        
    fn func(&mut self) -> &'a mut T {
        // Option::take() 
        let node = self.0.take().unwrap();

        &mut node.0
    }
}
```

My confusion is why the lifetime of reference `node` returned by `Option::take()` satisfy the lifetime `'a` ?

Comment: Considering the first example you may just remove the lifetime of the result and it will work, or use the signature `fn func<'b:'a>(&'b mut self) -> &'a mut T`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't it you connect the liftime passed to wrapper to the inner one here:

```rust
struct Wrapper<'a, T: 'a>(Option<&'a mut Node<T>>);
```

so I don't get why you're suprised it lives for the `'a` defined here:

```rust
impl<'a, T: 'a> Wrapper<'a, T> {
```

By using `take` you remove the reference from the object so it doesn't matter if the object is later dropped.

Your first example keeps the reference inside the original object and borrows from it instead of taking the reference out so in addition to the `'a` constraint it cannot outlive the original object.